# Infer generic type argument from parameter type of function in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript, type-inference, generic-programming

I want to create a `toPlainObject()` function in TypeScript and have come up with that working example:

```
function toPlainObject<S extends D, D>(source: S) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source)) as D;
}
```

Now I can invoke the function like this:

```
interface ISample {}
class Sample implements ISample {}

let plain: ISample = toPlainObject<Sample, ISample>(new Sample());
```

Now the question: Is there a way I could declare `toPlainObject`without the need of the first generic type argument `S extends D` by using the first parameter type (which is `S`) so that I could invoke the function by just doing:

```
let plain: ISample = toPlainObject<ISample>(new Sample());
```

The signature `function toPlainObject<D>(source: S extends D) { ... }` does **not** work and results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand what you are after, but I don't see why you can't just do:

```
interface ISample {}
class Sample implements ISample {}

function toPlainObject<TInterface>(source: TInterface) : TInterface {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source)) as TInterface;
}

let plain: ISample = toPlainObject(new Sample());
```

Also your sample works for me no problem (TypeScript 1.8.10)

```
interface ISample {}
class Sample implements ISample {}

function toPlainObject<S extends D, D>(source: S) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source)) as D;
}

let plain: ISample = toPlainObject(new Sample());
```

Comment: Of course, I was thinking overly complicated :) Your solution works, however I'd still be interested how one could accomplish this by infering the type from the argument.

Comment: @Dyna I've updated my answer. Your sample works for me. All generics are inferred without any need for supplying them.